# Writing text in equation

Tags: equations, text

I can correctly write equation containing text, in [latex equation editor online](https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php).
So:

```
\text{Micro-averaged Precision} = \frac{TP_{total}}{TP_{total} + FP_{total}}
```

Gives:
[image]

In Overleaf, this is displayed somehow not as intended (without space):

[image]

With the `Undefined control sequence.` error.

Comment: don't ignore errors, you presumably got an error tha `\text` was not defined, load `amsmath` package. Also use `_{\mathrm{total}}` don't use math italic for words

Comment: thank you. it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't ignore errors, you presumably got an error that `\text` was not defined, load amsmath package. Also use `_{\mathrm{total}}` don't use math italic for words